# SonarQube vulnerability: Replace this persistent entity with POJO/DTO

Tags: java, spring-boot, sonarqube

```
@PostMapping("/create")
public ResponseEntity<TaskDTO> create(@RequestBody Task task){
    return new ResponseEntity<>(this.service.createTask(task), HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

So this is part of my task controller, I have put my project into SonarQube and it's telling me this is a security risk. Why does this piece of code cause problems and how would I change this to make it better?

Comment: Is there any more details to share in addition to "security risk"?

Answer (score 0):

If your Task class has annotations, so that it is used to store Task instances in a database
 AND it is used as input parameter of a Controller's incoming request method,
 then you get this Sonarqube vulnerability.

To solve it you need 2 classes for Task:

- One to receive only the input data for your Controller
- Another one to write it in the database (called DAO)

And you need some kind of mapping logic to translate from one class to the other.